# JQuery ruler not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to get JQuery ruler (http://ruler.hilliuse.com/) (https://github.com/hilliuse/Ruler) working, but it's not happening.

```
    $('body').ruler({
    vRuleSize: 18,
    hRuleSize: 18,
    showCrosshair : true,
    showMousePos: true
}); 

$('#ruler_box').ruler({
    vRuleSize: 18,
    hRuleSize: 18,
    showCrosshair : true,
    showMousePos: true
});
```

See fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/A3xGm/

Comment: Check the console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Modernizr is not defined`. Looks like that plugin depends on Modernizr

Comment: Yep, that was the problem...no reference on either site that I could see to modernzr...  Looks like the ruler plugin doesn't work on div elements, just body...  Wanna put you comment into an answer?

Comment: Actually it does work on divs...see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963257/drawing-consistant-line-length-against-ruler-using-fabric-js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plugin depends on Modernizr.

Check it this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pqz6P/) - it works when you add modernizr as an external resource.

```
// Just because jsfiddle links need to be accompanied by code
$(function() {
  $('body').ruler();    
});
```

[Here's a link to the latest version of modernizr](http://modernizr.com/downloads/modernizr-latest.js)

Comment: nice plugin. For those not using modernizr, you will need to edit jquery.ruler.js and comment out lines 28-56, which is the code block that starts with "if (!Modernizr.touch) {", otherwise the plugin will not work.

Answer (score 2):

You can try a [jquery-ui.ruler](https://github.com/efernandesng/jquery-ui.ruler) . Is a simple jqueryUI plugin that have nive features:

- Multiple units (px, mm, cm, in)
- Three types of ticks (major, minor,
  micro)
- Mouse track
- Supports sub-divs

Answer (score 1):

jQuery ruler will work with modernizr. so include modernizer.js.

Here is the link for modernize.js file
http://modernizr.com/downloads/modernizr-latest.js

```
 // Just because jsfiddle links need to be accompanied by code
 $(function() {
     $('body').ruler();    
 });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kprajapati22/3xZrq/)